# What are unauthenticated and authenticated requests in github?

Tags: github

I am running a script which clones multiple repositories in my GitHub project organization. After running the script twice or thrice, I get an 128 error

```
git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/project-xyz/abc.git failed with exit code 128
```

and this works again after some time. I am guessing that this is a rate limiting issue.

Github page says ratelimit for unauthenticated requests is 60 per hour and I guess I am hitting that by running my script multiple times. My ssh key is added to Github.

I was under the assumption that cloning git repos using ssh are considered authenticated requests. My error leads me to believe that those are treated as unauthenticated requests.

I want to know what are differences between authenticated and unauthenticated requests in GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

First, check the SSH access with:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

And fix the URL: it should be

```
ssh://git@github.com/project-xyz/abc.git
# not
ssh://git@wwwgithub.com/project-xyz/abc.git
```

Second, the [rate limiting is for API calls](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) (Example: `curl -i https://api.github.com/users/octocat`)

I suppose any kind of direct Git call to GitHub would be limited, authenticated or not.

Comment: Sorry I missed the www while cleaning the URL . I can SSH to git using my key. Able to ssh was not a problem. I am not able to find an answer to if clone via ssh is being treated as unauthenticated request.

Comment: @kid A clone with SSH is authenticated. But the rate limit is about API calls, not SSH URLs, as I mention in the answer above.